# Magento 2 : How to move a block next to size attribute label on product page. [Size Chart]

Tags: magento2.3, layout, blocks, product-attribute, xml

I want to move a block next to size attribute label:

[image]

How can I do this?

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can not move block between two configurable options via `xml`. Configurable product attributes are render by `vendor\magento\module-configurable-product\view\frontend\templates\product\view\type\options\configurable.phtml`. So if you want to display block next to `size` attribute you have to override this file, and call your block in this file.

Comment: Yes, @IvannVerano It is right.You are not call configurable options via xml.So you try phtml file.

Comment: Yeees!!! Works Thank you very much Sebastian!!!!

Comment: You're welcome!